# CakePHP 1.3: Cache Enabled. Cake not clearing cache at article post

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and Caching most of my elements. From what I read, Cake is supposed to clear the cache when a new post is created. However, it is not working for me automatically?

I typically use a plugin to clear the cache or I do this manually thru FTP.

Anyone has a suggestion for me that would make my life easier by having cake perform this for me AUTOMAGICALLY?

thanks,

Comment: How do you cache? Only http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html this will auto-clear the cache and only if the conditions are met that are described on this page.

Comment: I just noticed that the elements cached on the articles view are being refreshed. However, I have elements that referenced the articles controllers in the frontpage(pages controller) that do not get refreshed. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe CakePHP clears cache in the following manner:

1. If there is an element ie. `articles_most_viewed.ctp` and it is called from within `articles index.ctp` file, then Cake will clear that respective element during an add, edit, delete action.
2. However, if there is an element ie. `frontpage_lastest_articles.ctp` and it is only called in `pages/display.ctp` file (frontpage), then CakePHP will not clear that element since it is not being called from within the affected/changed model/view, in this case `articles` model/controller/view.

I havent figure out how to better approach this issue, if there is a better way. However, my quick fix is to call `clearCache()` in my `admin_add.ctp`, `admin_edit.ctp` and `admin_delete.ctp` files as such:

```
...
function admin_add(){
    ...
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Article->save($this->data)) {
            // I call the following function to clear my entire Cache directory
            // after this action is successfully processed
            // ===========================================
            clearCache();
            // ===========================================
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

There might be a better way to handle this, but this is my solution for now. I would be glad to know if there is a better/automagic solution.